# What is the difference between "when we are" and "when we will be"?

Tags: conditionals, future-tense

Please help me understand the difference between these two statements.

1. I hope we can all celebrate when we are back in office.
2. I hope we can all celebrate when we will be back in office.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one difference.

1. is correct and 2. is wrong.

You say future things like this : If it rains tomorrow, I will go there tomorrow

If you say "If it will rain tomorrow,~", it's not correct.